# FindControl from asp.net Listview Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I have Listview & few radiobutton list. Inside Listview I have put one hyperlink control. Now When from radiobuttonList particular value get selected then only that hyperlink control should be visible. I tried FIndControl From listview But it gives this error.

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

```
<asp:ListView ID="orderList" runat="server" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder1"
ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1" OnPagePropertiesChanging="OnPagePropertiesChanging">
                     <LayoutTemplate>
                         <table class="online-orders">
                     <thead>
                         <tr>
                             <th>Order ID</th>
                             <th>Patient Name</th>         
                             <th>Actions</th>
                         </tr>
                     </thead>
                             <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8">
                        <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="orderList" PageSize="10">
                            <Fields>
                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true"
                                    ShowNextPageButton="false" />
                                <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />
                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />
                            </Fields>
                        </asp:DataPager>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                             </table>
                     </LayoutTemplate>

                     <GroupTemplate>
                         <tr>
                             <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                         </tr>
                     </GroupTemplate>

                    <ItemTemplate>
                     <tbody>
                         <tr>
                             <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OrderID") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                             <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                             <td>
                                 <asp:Label ID="status" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                                 <asp:HyperLink ID="decline" CssClass="decline-order-icon" NavigateUrl='<%# "decline-order.aspx?orderID=" & Eval("orderID") %>' Target="_blank" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:HyperLink>
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     </tbody>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:ListView>
```

vb code

```
Private Sub orderFilter_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles orderFilter.SelectedIndexChanged
            Dim processing As HyperLink = CType(orderList.Items(orderList.SelectedIndex).FindControl("decline"), HyperLink)
            If orderFilter.SelectedValue = "processing" Then
                processing.Visible = True
            End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not `FindControl`, but `orderList.Items(orderList.SelectedIndex)` that gives you this error. My guess is that no items are selected in the ListView at the moment, and so `SelectedIndex` returns -1 (as described in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Note that this is very well possible -  you are handling selection change of some other control named `orderFilter`, or at least event handler name `orderFilter_SelectedIndexChanged` suggest so. So there is no guarantee that anything is selected in `orderList`.

First piece of advice here is to make sure this makes sense and there is no error in this. Perhaps you really need to handle selection change of `orderList` instead of `orderFilter`?

Second piece is to check for -1 anyway, in case selection changed to be empty:

```
Private Sub orderFilter_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles orderFilter.SelectedIndexChanged
    If orderList.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        Return
    End If

    Dim processing As HyperLink = CType(orderList.Items(orderList.SelectedIndex).FindControl("decline"), HyperLink)
    If orderFilter.SelectedValue = "processing" Then
                processing.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What I want is if value processing is selected then only then hyperlink should get visible. But it's not working. It's still not visible

Comment: Try to debug this. That might be happening because `orderList.SelectedIndex = -1` is in fact true, which means you have nothing selected in this list. Make sure you do not rebind this list on postback though